# MVC code first Database not seeding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

when I  initialise the database in Global.asax
Database.SetInitializer(new Models.TeamInits());
 but when I run the code the database creates but it has no tables, I tried to initialise it in the webconfig which worked in VS 2013 but since I upgraded to vs 2015, it no longer works any help please.

```
    protected override void Seed(TeamContext context)
    {
        var teams = new List<Team>
            {
                new Team(){TeamName = "Team1", Players = new List<Player> { new Player{PlayerName = "Bav", HighScore = 25 }, new Player {PlayerName = "NAD", HighScore = 35 } } },
                new Team(){TeamName = "Team2", Players = new List<Player> { new Player{PlayerName = "Bavva", HighScore = 25 }, new Player {PlayerName = "dads", HighScore = 3554 } } },
                new Team(){TeamName = "Team3", Players = new List<Player> { new Player { PlayerName = "Bav", HighScore = 25 }, new Player {PlayerName = "Mama", HighScore = 35 } }  },
                new Team(){TeamName = "Team4", Players = new List<Player> { new Player{PlayerName = "Bav", HighScore = 25 }, new Player {PlayerName = "waws", HighScore = 456156  }  } },
                new Team(){TeamName = "Team5" }

            };

        teams.ForEach(t => context.Teams.Add(t));
        context.SaveChanges();


    }

}

public class Team
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

}

public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    public int HighScore { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

}

public class TeamContext : DbContext
{

    public TeamContext()
        : base("TeamContext")
    { }

    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }


}
```